# SSRS implement mailto function with HTML table

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, microsoft-reporting

I am creating a SSRS report. I have added a mailto button, when the user press on that button. It will open outlook and create an email with the recipient email automatically.

Now, I would like parse the table on the SSRS to outlook email, in this case the user doesn't need to copy and paste the table from SSRS to outlook email. I have searched that the maximum length for the mailto statement is 255 characters. I would like to know is there any tricks? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

255 is not limited by SSRS, it is Url path limit. Hence, you cannot trick your mail client in this way.

But you may develop **Rendering Extension** so that user can send email just like exporting to excel. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/extensions-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017#rendering-extensions)